How to read text messages over Bluetooth like a car does (in any language)?
Every car I’ve had can read text message updates after being synced over Bluetooth. There’s no app installed on my phone.
How do they do it?
Is there a spec I need to implement to do it also?
I basically want a Python app on my computer to visualize the text notifications in real time, like a car does.
I’ve googled how cars do it but it doesn’t bring up relevant results.

There is standard Bluetooth protocol for that. Depending on a phone model/supported features it can be: Message Access Profile (MAP), Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) some other (refer to Bluetooth specifications)

@MikePetrichenko “ANCS” oh wow, that’s interesting! I have an iPhone and found this node library that seemingly implemented it. https://github.com/robotastic/ble-ancs
